# How is it possible to put a PivotTable on a different sheet using Aspose Cells?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, aspose-cells

I see [here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Pivot+Table+and+Source+Data) how to create a PivotTable on the same sheet as the source data, like so:

```
int index = pivotTables.Add("=A1:C8", "E3", "PivotTable2");
```

The first arg `("=A1:C8")` is the source data to extract, the second `("E3")` is the cell that will serve as the NW corner of the PivotTable - on the same sheet.

I need to put my PivotTable on a separate sheet (and then hide the source data tab altogether).

How can I specify that the second argument is on another sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, your data is inside the worksheet named "MyDataSheet" and your cell range is A1:D25, then your source data will be **MyDataSheet!A1:D25**, now select any of your worksheet and add the pivot table like this.

```
anySheet.PivotTables.Add("MyDataSheet!A1:D25", "E3", "MyPivot");
```

It will now add pivot table inside the **anySheet** but the data will come from **MyDataSheet**.

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose